# How to insert an inline image in Google Colaboratory markdown call from local path

Tags: image, markdown, google-colaboratory

This is not a duplicate of [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478791/how-can-i-open-images-in-a-google-colaboratory-notebook-cell-from-uploaded-png-f).

The original poster accepted a solution that didn't correspond exactly to his request:

> I am working with a Google Colaboratory notebook. I uploaded a file named bp.png into the working directory, and I can see that the file is in there by running !ls in a code cell. Then I try this piece of code to see the image in a markdown cell:

The solution proposed involved posting the image in a **code** cell.

I'm trying to see if somebody has a solution for a **markdown** cell.

I have noticed the markdown img tag works with a valid url, but not with a local path; Is there a way to find an equivalent url for a file path known to lead to the correct file? `<h2 align="center">Image</h2> <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5150aec6e4b0e340ec52710a/t/51525c33e4b0b3e0d10f77ab/1364352052403/Data_Science_VD.png?format=250w" >`**works**, but not with `/tmp/image.png` or other absolute or relative path.

Answer (score 1):

This won't link to a local file per se, but you can convert a local file into a [data url](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). [This site](http://dataurl.net/) will create a data url from an image, which you can use as an image url in a markdown cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your image within here

`/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/google.colab/`

Then access it with path `/nbextensions/google.colab/`, e.g.

```
%%html
<img src='/nbextensions/google.colab/image.png' />
```

The image will be cached, so be careful about updating it.

Read more details from [this snippet](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#snippetFileIds=%2Fv2%2Fexternal%2Fnotebooks%2Fsnippets%2Fadvanced_outputs.ipynb&snippetQuery=Serving%20resources)