# Rendering inline images in markdown in Colab

Tags: markdown, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use a local image path that is referenced in a markdown cell.

```
![foo image caption stuff ](../img/functionclasses.svg)
```

However, as the notebook is loaded directly into colab, the browser cannot see this local directory structure. Is it possible to load the entire file from drive and then navigate through it to the notebook I want such that the images are able to load properly (and in-line)?

---

Note: There are 150 .ipynb notebooks in this folder so I'm looking for a good solution that doesn't require manually editing every notebook (such as adding the URL by hand).

This is probably possible to fix by manually editing each image in each notebook, but I'm looking for a more stable solution.

Edit 1: I saw this answer: ([How can I open images in a Google Colaboratory notebook cell from uploaded png files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478791/how-can-i-open-images-in-a-google-colaboratory-notebook-cell-from-uploaded-png-f))

However, I can't seem to find the directory /usr/local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/google.colab/ on my local machine. Do I need to create it?