# can't show an image using PIL on google colab

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use PIL to show an image. I know that I can use other modules to do that. I am working on google colab. But I can't figure out why PIL is not showing output image.

```
% matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import PIL
im=Image.open('/content/drive/My Drive/images-process.jpeg')
print(im.width, im.height, im.mode, im.format, type(im))
im.show()
```

output: 739 415 RGB JPEG < class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>

Comment: I don't know or use Colab, but PIL's `Image.show()` actually saves a temporary file and asks the underlying OS to display it using its built-in image viewer whatever that is. Does that sound like it should work on Colab?

Comment: I actually don't know about Colab's underlaying OS. I only know that it's built on top of jupyter notebook

Comment: If it's a browser type of environment it may not work. Maybe try matplotlib.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Instead of

```
im.show()
```

Try just

```
im
```

Colab should try to display it on its own. See [example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1D1FTlxu1Ty4JtDw9J_vNOxl2hC6WYe6I)

Comment: Do I need to write `im` immediately after reading the image? I tried writing `im` after couple of statement. In that case, the example didn't work

Comment: You can type `im` anywhere after loading. But it must be the last line in that cell. If it's not the last line, you must use `display(im)` instead.

Comment: Interesting, colab has a magic display() function! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Use

```
display(im)
```

instead of `im.show()` or `im`.

When using these options after multiple lines or in a loop, `im` won't work.

Comment: Hmm.. now how to write code internal to a package that uses `im.show()` but get it to render in Google Colab via `display(im)`.

Answer (score 0):

After you open an image(which you have done using Image.open()), try converting using im.convert() to which ever mode image is in then do display(im)

It will work